# How do I create a tab separated file from a hive query?

Tags: insert, save, hive, create-table, csv

I am trying to create a tab separated value from a hive query.

Following the Apache Hive wiki, I composed my query as:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/luca/query_results/'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY  '\t' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
SELECT * FROM mytable ;
```

(please note, that the real query is quite complex, I know I could have used `hive -e "Select * from mytable > output` in this simple case).

The query seems to work, but in the query_results directory I find one file with `.snappy` extension, and when I open it it seems to be a binary file, not a text file.

What is wrong with my query? How can I get the results of my query in a nicely formatted text file (I want to write an hive script that returns several such files. If I can even specify the name of the file from within hive it would be a bonus).

Comment: I guess disabling the snappy compression would solve the .snappy file issue.set hive.exec.compress.output=false;

Comment: @KSNidhin thanks, I wasn't aware of this. So I have two more questions now :p since the query takes a lot of time, would it be possible to uncompress the .snappy file I already created? For the next queries, can I specify the name of the file, rather than the directory?

Comment: @KSNidhin could you post your comment as an answer? I believe it's an actual answer

Comment: @arghtype I was going to try the query again, if it works I would have asked KSNidhin as well :)

Comment: @lucacerone you could check this without running actual query: run 'set hive.exec.compress.output' in hive client, if it returns true, than you have default compression enabled

Comment: @arghtype yep it is set to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the comment as answer

The .snappy file issue could be resolved by unsetting the compression.
Use the following :

```
      set hive.exec.compress.output=false
```

The once snappy compressed file cannot be decompressed becuase of its encoded structure.

The above compression property can either be set permanently in the hive-site.xml or you can do it manually every time you run an insert query

Comment: thanks, I have noticed that the file created by insert overwrite do not have an header (I already set the hive value to include the header in my queries, is there any way I can also include it in the table exported using insert overwrite?)

Comment: i dont think hive supports that now. Since its more focused on data than its metadata, which can be found separately.

Comment: If your metastore is configured in Mysql , you could get it the TBLS , DBS tables avaialable in the metastore DB

Answer (score 0):

To open  .snappy extension we need to use text syntax in query.